# $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then $V[a,x]$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, bounded-variation

Can someone help to check my proof? [Notation.](https://books.google.com/books?id=30FZDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. For any $x_0,x_1$ in $[a,b]$, $|f(x_0)-f(x_1)|\to 0$ as $|x_0-x_1|\to 0$.

W.L.O.G., suppose $a\le z_0<z_1\le b$, and let $|z_0-z_1|\to 0$. Consider the partition $P_0$ of $[a,z_0]$ and the partition $P_1$ of $[a,z_1]$. Hence, $\bar{P}=P_0\cup P_1$ is a refinement of $P_1$. Then, we can split the partition $\bar{P}$ by $$A=\bar{P}\cap[a,z_0] \text{ and } B=\bar{P}\cap[z_0,z_1].$$

So, \begin{align*}S_\bar{P}[a,z_1]-S_{P_0}[a,z_0] &=S_A[a,z_0]+S_B[z_0,z_1]-S_{P_0}[a,z_0].
\end{align*}

Note that if $|\bar{P}|\to 0$, then $|P_0|\to 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $$\lim_{|\bar{P}|\to 0}S_{\bar{P}}[a,z_1] = V[a,z_1] \text{ and } \lim_{|\bar{P}|\to 0} S_{P_0}[a,z_0] = V[a,z_0].$$

Hence, \begin{align*}V[a,z_1]-V[a,z_0] &= V[a,z_0]+V[z_0,z_1]-V[a.z_0]\\
 &= V[z_0,z_1].
\end{align*}

Since $B$ is a partition of $[z_0,z_1]$ with finitely many points and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[z_0,z_1]$, we conclude that $V[z_0,z_1]\to 0$ as $|z_0-z_1|\to 0$.

---

I could use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, but I would need to find the precise value of $\delta$ such that $|x_0-x_1|<\delta \implies |f(x_0)-f(x_1)|<\epsilon$. Is this proof valid? Do I need to make any improvement?

Comment: You have the general idea right but some details are wrong and some are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of your argument up to the equation following "Hence" involves unnecessary and inaccurate reasoning to prove simply that

$$\tag{*} V[a,z_1] = V[a,z_0] + V[z_0,z_1]$$

For example, the assertion that $|\bar{P}| \to 0$ implies $|P_0| \to 0$ is false. We can have $|P_1| \to 0$ and $|\bar{P}| \to 0$ while $P_0$ stays fixed.  Furthermore, continuity of $f$ is not required to prove (*).

If we take a partition $P$ of $[a,z_0]$ and a partition $P'$ of $[z_0,z_1]$, then $P'' = P \cup P'$ is a partition of $[a,z_1]$ and $S_P[a,z_0] + S_{P'}[z_0,z_1] = S_{P''}[a,z_1]$.

This implies that $S_P[a,z_0] + S_{P'}[z_0,z_1] \leqslant V[a,z_1]$, and  taking suprema on the LHS we get

$$V[a,z_0] + V[z_0,z_1] \leqslant  V[a,z_1] $$

Another straightforward argument gives us the reverse inequality, thereby proving (*).

With that out of the way, we can move on to the final part of your  argument where you conclude that $V[z_0,z_1] \to 0 $ as $|z_0 - z_1| \to 0$ because $f$ is uniformly continuous and a partition has a finite number of points -- both obviously true but inessential facts.  This is the crux of the proof that the total variation is continuous, and you have simply made an assertion without supplying any details.

For a correct proof, first prove right-continuity by showing that

$$\lim_{z_1 \to z_0+} V[z_0,z_1] = 0$$

By continuity of $f$, given $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\xi > z_0$ such that $|f(z_1) - f(z_0)| < \epsilon/2$ if $z_0 < z_1 < \xi$. Also since total variation is a supremum over partitions, there is a partition $z_0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ of $[z_0,b]$ such that

$$V[z_0,b] < \sum_{k=1}^n|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| + \epsilon/2$$

If $x_0 = z_0 < z_1 < \min(x_1,\xi)$ then $|f(x_1) - f(x_0)| \leqslant |f(z_1) - f(x_0)| +|f(x_1) - f(z_1)| $

and

$$V[z_0,b] < |f(z_1) - f(z_0)| + |f(x_1) - f(z_1)| + \sum_{k=2}^n|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| + \epsilon/2 \\< \epsilon/2 + |f(x_1) - f(z_1)| + \sum_{k=2}^n|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| + \epsilon/2\\ < V[z_1,b] + \epsilon $$

This implies for all $z_0 < z_1 < \min(x_1,\xi)$ we have

$$V[z_0,z_1] = V[z_0,b] - V[z_1,b] < \epsilon,$$

which completes the proof of right-continuity.  By a similar argument we can prove left-continuity.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I appreciate it. And I think I should have clarified some notations. By definition of the norm of partition, $|P|$ is defined as the length of a longest subinterval of $P$: $|P|=\max_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$, where $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_m\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. I might be correct to say that $|\bar{P}| \to 0$ implies $|P_0| \to 0$?

Comment: Could you tell me which part do you refer to by "This is the crux of the proof that the total variation is continuous, and you have simply made an assertion without supplying any details."?

Comment: I wanted to show if $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then $V[a,x]$ is continuous. So, to prove $V[a,x]$ is continuous, I tried to show that $|V[a,z_1] - V[a,z_0]|\to 0$ as $|z_0-z_1|\to 0$. And since $|V[a,z_0] - V[a,z_1]| = V[a,z_1] - V[a,z_0]$, I tried to show $V[a,z_1] - V[a,z_0] \to 0$ as $|z_0-z_1|\to 0$. Can we prove it in this way?

Comment: Say $a =0$,$z_0 = 1$ and $z_1 =2$.  Take $P_0 = (0,1)$ and $P_1 = (0,1/2,3/2,2)$. Then $\bar{P} = (0,1/2,1,3/2,2)$. You could refine $P_1$ and hence, $\bar{P}$ without changing $P_0$.  On the other hand, I would say let $P$ and $P_0$ be refined together so that $|P_0| \to 0$ and $|P| \to 0$.  It's not a critical point.  I think its better to prove additivity of total variation directly from the definition as I showed, but your approach will work.  It just is a well-known fact that can be stated up front to facilitate the important part of the proof.

Comment: @user398843: "I tried to show $V[a,z_1] - V[a,z_0] \to 0$ as $|z_0 -z_1| \to 0$".  That is what it means to be continuous which is what you are trying to prove.  You simply said its true because $f$ is uniformly continuous and a partition has a finite number of points.  You did not prove it -- so I showed you how.

Comment: I started something and deleted as it seemed you understood now.  Good job.

Comment: I thought to show $V[z_0,z_1]\to 0$ as $|z_1-z_0|\to 0$, I just need to say that (1) given a partition $P'$ of $[z_0,z_1]$, $\sum|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$; (2) the partition has finite number of points, so the sum has finite terms; (3) the uniform continuity of $f$ guarantees that  as $|z_1-z_0| \to 0$, $|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$ is sufficiently small so that the sum is less than $\epsilon$; (4) since the partition is arbitrary, we then conclude that the supremum is less than $\epsilon$. (I ignore the equal sign as we can take the sum in (3) to be smaller so that the sup is less than $\epsilon$.)

Comment: Is my reasoning above correct? I didn't come up with the idea of proving right-continuity and left-continuity

Comment: So take partition $P = (z_0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = z_1)$ where $z_1$ is close enough to $z_0$ such that $|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}| < \epsilon$ for $k = 1,\ldots ,n$.  Then $S_P = \sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}| < n\epsilon$. Does that mean $V[z_0,z_1] < n\epsilon$ with $n$ fixed?  Not necessarily since $V[z_0,z_1] = \sup_P S_P$ and that sup is taken over many partitions with more than $n$ points .  We would need that $|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \to 0$ faster than $1/n$ and we are not given much about $f$ other than continuity.